# I got a Null safety error while using Stream Builder. How to get rid of null safety?

Tags: flutter, dart-null-safety

My main.dart code :

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(MyApp());

}



class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {


    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: StreamBuilder<User?>(
          stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
            if(snapshot.hasData){
              return Imageslider();
            } else {
              return MyLogin();
            }
          },
```

I'm getting a null safety error.

**Error :

( Exception caught by widgets library)
The following _CastError was thrown building StreamBuilder<User?>(state: _StreamBuilderBaseState<User?, AsyncSnapshot<User?>>#79771):
Null check operator used on a null value**

Comment: Could please use User instead of User?.

Comment: @HarshSureja Why? If you know this is the problem, please post an answer. If you don't, then don't post guesses. They just confuse people.

Comment: I did not post guesses. I just tell possible  solutions.

Comment: Well, it's not a possible solution. And if you posted it as an answer, I would be able to downvote it, or maybe you would be able to explain why it's a solution and I would see the reasoning. This way, it's "an answer posted as a comment", something that is not supposed to be.

Comment: @HarshSureja, I'm getting an error if I use "User" instead of "User?". The error -> "The argument type 'Stream<User?>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Stream<User>?'."

Comment: could please share User class code?

Comment: Apart from the fact that "User" is not the OPs own class, there is *nothing* that could possibly be in that class that would fix the error the OP posted in comments. Please stop random guessing.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you understand what is happening here. "Null safety" is a relatively new Dart feature and **it is your friend**. You don't want to get rid of it.

This feature tries to warn you if something is `null` when you are using it. You can *disable* this feature, by just putting a `!` behind the offending variable. That will make your compiler shut up about it. But it doesn't solve the actual problem, that this variable might be null. Putting a `!` to "solve" null safety problems is basically turning of the fire alarm, with the fire still burning. The alarm doesn't beep any more, but it will still ruin everything.

So, you don't want to disable null safety. Matter of fact, chances are you disabled it already somewhere and now the reality strikes: you just shut up the useful alarm and never solved the actual problem.

Look into `Imageslider` and `MyLogin`.

> Null check operator used on a null value

This means you used a `!` to silence your compiler, but it turned out your compiler was right and now you have an error.

So go through your code and throw out every single `!` that you used for null safety (so the ones *after* variable names... keep the ones in front of variable names, they have a different meaning). Now your code won't compile. Great. So now you know all your problems. And now, you need to *fix* them. *Solve* the problem instead of just telling your compiler to ignore them.

Since I don't know what those problems are, I cannot really help you. As a general guideline, most of the time, you will probably need an `if` or `x : y ?  z` expression to tell your compiler what to do if the value does indeed turn out to be null. For example if the user is null, you cannot display the user's name, you could display an empty `Container()` instead.

If you cannot find the problem following these steps, feel free to post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can check it.